# Как удалить каждый n-ый элемент в списке с помощью Stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream, функциональное-программирование

У меня есть некий `ArrayList<String>`, как мне с помощью стримов удалять каждый 5 элемент?

Comment: В этом [вопросе на англоязычном StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602425/take-every-nth-element-from-a-java-8-stream) есть ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<String> filteredList = list.stream().filter(new Predicate<String>() {
    int counter = 1;
    @Override
    public boolean test(String s) {
        return counter++ % 5 != 0;
    }
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод принимает исходную коллекцию, возвращает новую после удаления

```
public List<T> delEveryFive(List<T> list) {
return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
    .filter(n -> n % 5 != 0) //5 - каждый 5 эл-т удаляется. 
    .mapToObj(list::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602425/take-every-nth-element-from-a-java-8-stream)

Comment: Ваш код оставит каждый пятый элемент. Нужно `n % 5 != 0`.

Comment: @talex упс, спасибо

Comment: Решение рабочее, но должен заметить, подобное применение стримов - это антипаттерн. Не желательно работать с данными за пределами стрима. Как только появляется идея об обращении к переменной, стоит насторожиться и подумать "Я использую стримы неправильно или стримы тут вообще не подходят?"

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а как лучше? Мне приходит в голову только 1 способ: циклы. Но автор же попросил именно со стримами

Comment: Не уверен, но думаю, что для такой задачи хорошо подошло бы написание собственного коллектора или сплитератора.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev а можно пример подкинуть на коллектор или сплитер ?

Comment: @Fox может быть позже, работы завал :)

Comment: Да не вопрос, не к спеху.